# the login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer - Without Auto Login

Tags: login, password, authentication, fingerprint-reader, pam

i know this is a repeated question but in may case Auto Login is not turned on.
instead i have enabled Fingerprint Login and enabled Fingerprint Authentication module using pam-auth-update.
so i use Fingerprint authentication for Login/Sudo.
is there any way i can stop this message from appearing repeatedly when i log in with Fingerprint Authentication.

no issue with Finger Print Auth setup in Fedora Workstation, i switched to Fedora from 18.04 as i was very annoyed by this issue earlier. It would frequently throw this message at me whenever i open a browser/App/login and had to enter the password manually.
pls suggest a fix for this issue if any as i Have installed Ubuntu 22.04 after a long time.

Thanks

[Error Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH3eJ.jpg)

Comment: The keyring uses your password to decrypt, so with a fingerprint login, you cannot access the keyring (for things like email) until you supply the decryption key (password).  That's why I found fingerprint login somewhat useless.

Comment: I don't think you can fix this unless you remove the password from your keyring (not recommended).